# Why doesn't oxygen replace chlorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

If oxygen is more electronegative why doesn't it replace chlorine in compounds?

Example:

$\ce{2NaBr + Cl2 -> 2NaCl + Br2}$

works, while

$\ce{4NaCl + O2 -> 2Na2O + 2Cl2}$

doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* displace chlorine [from *hydrogen chloride*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qA1DAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=hydrogen+chloride+is+oxidized+by+oxygen+gas&source=bl&ots=AXm3awhTdB&sig=oj-x3j6i3nattgT45WfR38ePKoo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_mbz_r5vZAhWNv1MKHfnBCkwQ6AEwCXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=hydrogen%20chloride%20is%20oxidized%20by%20oxygen%20gas&f=false).

With sodium chloride, if you did form sodium oxide it would be a strong base.  As such it extracts a $\ce{Cl^+}$ moiety from any potential chlorine molecules.  Sodium chloride is oxidized by oxygen, but the oxidized chlorine ends up as chlorine oxyanions such as hypochlorite (i.e., oxide coordinated to chlorine).

Comment: It's redox not acid base.

Comment: Why would it not be both?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you even mean in this. Proper answer is that O2 has to low redox potential.

Comment: Then say so in your own answer.

Comment: Re: "chlorine gets oxidized to oxyanions such hypochlorite" So, the products formed from $\ce{Na2O\+Cl2}$ are $\ce{NaCl\+NaOCl}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to know if a reaction is spontaneous or not (if it will happen towards the direction you have drawn it) you must look at its Gibbs energy, ΔG. Electronegativity of one element in a reaction is one of the many factors that contribute to it. In this case you are dealing with a redox reaction (because the oxidation states of the elements involved change) and therefore you need to use the relationship: ΔG=-nFE$^0$cell with E$^0$cell calculated from the relevant half reactions. For more details read an introduction to electrochemistry from some inorganic chemistry book.